# mysql How to COUNT() nulleble fields + IFNULL

Tags: mysql, sql

field version can have null but i need to count such rows too
i tried to do like this : IFNULL(COUNT(version), 1) , but not work

```
select MIN(id) as id, version, IFNULL(COUNT(version), 1) as total
from hlrlookup.hlrlookup
WHERE create_timestamp > '2015-02-01 05:00:00' and create_timestamp < '2016-04-28 06:00:00'
group by version;
```

help

Answer (score 2):

`COUNT()` never returns `NULL` -- it returns `0` instead.  If you want to count all rows, then use `COUNT(*)`:

```
select MIN(id) as id, version, COUNT(*) as total
from hlrlookup.hlrlookup
WHERE create_timestamp > '2015-02-01 05:00:00' and
      create_timestamp < '2016-04-28 06:00:00'
GROUP BY version;
```

EDIT:

I should note that the correct way of expressing the logic you were trying to do is:

```
select MIN(id) as id, version, GREATEST(COUNT(version), 1) as total
. . .
```

Comment: in my case version can have 1...100 value and null, i think better first, thank you

Answer (score 0):

You have `version` in group by statement. You can just sum rows for each version:

```
select MIN(id) as id, version, SUM(1) as total
from hlrlookup.hlrlookup
WHERE create_timestamp > '2015-02-01 05:00:00' and create_timestamp < '2016-04-28 06:00:00'
group by version;
```